# What libraries can adjust exposure with Opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, vision

I'm trying to adjust the exposure of a Microsoft LifeCam HD 3000 with Opencv3, but (CV_CAP_PROP_GAIN, value from 0 to 1) it has does not work. Are there any other libraries that work with Opencv to adjust the exposure of a camera?

Answer (score 0):

```
cv::VideoCapture::set(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, value from 0 to 1); 
cv::VideoCapture::set(CV_CAP_PROP_GAIN, value from 0 to 1);
```

Both of these lines are needed not just the GAIN line.